# datacompy - How to output report string to an external file or within a cell in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter

I am trying to output a datacompy report to either a cell with Jupyter Notebooks as

```
print(comparison.report())
```

OR
Output the report to external s3 File as

```
import boto3   
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('s3://my-bucket/myfolder/', 'report.txt').put(Body=open(comparison.report(), 'rb'))
```

with the same error:

```
I/O operation on closed file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1650350526572-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datacompy/sparkcompare.py", line 849, in report
    self._print_columns_summary(file)
  File "/tmp/1650350526572-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datacompy/sparkcompare.py", line 273, in _print_columns_summary
    print("\n****** Column Summary ******", file=myfile)
  File "/tmp/7990806592050754376", line 534, in write
    super(UnicodeDecodingStringIO, self).write(s)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Any suggestions / solutions?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a valid file pointer first. At first I was concerned that the Spark executors would write to parallel files on each host, but this seemed to work normally:

```
with open("/tmp/report", 'w') as fp:
    compare.report(fp)

with open("/tmp/report", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

You can also upload that file to S3, just like you wanted. Keep in mind that bucket names do not include the `s3://` protocol nor the initial folder prefix (e.g. `"myfolder/"`). Folders are just implicit parts of the object's name.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('mybucket', 'path/to/report.txt').put(Body=open("/tmp/report", 'rb'))
```